running ./configure returns error: Cannot link with libtool libs! (libltdl)
I am attempting to compile an older program on a new system. I've done this a few times with this same software and I have always been able to find some way to get it to work but this time I am banging my head on the wall.
When I run ./configure it stops here:
checking libtool... checking for lt_dlinit in -lltdl... no
configure: error: Cannot link with libtool libs! (libltdl)
make: *** [Makefile:209: config.status] Error 1
I made sure that libtool and libltdl are available on this system.
Then I figured that perhaps the configure script was having some problems so I ran automake which told me that the aclocal.m4 was super old so I ran aclocal, then I ran automake and it created a new configure script but the error persists.
Here are the logs from config.log
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
a couple of mentions of this:
conftest.c:11:10: fatal error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or directory
11 | #include <ac_nonexistent.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Then I start seeing these:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkstat
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnsl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
and here is where the test configure complains about fails:
onfigure:9242: gcc -o conftest -g -O2  -L  conftest.c -lltdl  -lrt -lpthread -lm  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lltdl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:9251: result: no
configure:9261: error: Cannot link with libtool libs! (libltdl)
Does anyone have any ideas on anything else I can try to get this to compile?
Update:
I was able to get configure to complete by using the bootstrap.sh that was included in the original distribution.
When I run 'make' it now does this:
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config -I../cgilib-0.4  -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I -I/usr/include/net-snmp -I/usr/include/net-snmp/..  -g -O2 -MT rtgsnmp.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/rtgsnmp.Tpo -c -o rtgsnmp.o rtgsnmp.c
rtgsnmp.c:20:11: fatal error: net-snmp-config.h: No such file or directory
20 |  #include "net-snmp-config.h"
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
But of course here the file is: and it's even looking in the correct directory for it already....
find / -name net-snmp-config.h
/usr/include/net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h

Look whether you actually have libltdl.so in your default library directory, i.e. typically /usr/lib or something similar depending on distribution. Also -L conftest.c is wrong. -L should be followed by some library path. Have a look into the configure script to see whether some variable that should hold the path is accidentally empty when substituted in there.

@user17732522 find / -name libltdl.so*
/usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7
/usr/lib64/libltdl.so.7.3.1 is that what it should be?

There are multiple problems in one question here (bad!) and not enough info to reproduce either. Generally, when you just want to use a piece of software, then build issues are not really a good topic for SO. Instead, use the upstream bug tracker, first to check for existing reports and workarounds, then to file a bug yourself. For a question here, you'd need to extract a [mcve].

@ZCT I think (likely wrong here) with the option -lltdl the linker looks only for libltdl.so exactly, without suffix. Maybe the configure script has this hard coded while it should use pkg-config instead.
